# Load and delete an app programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, load

Is it possible on an iphone to programmatically load an app from another app? 
I know that you can link to the app in the appstore but I would like to load an app by entering for example its name and it is loaded without leaving the app which sent the order.

And the same question for deleting an app programmatically. For example having a list of all apps in your device and by pressing on one of them it is deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible on a non-jailbroken device, and for good reason. Depending on what you are selling though, you might want to consider the in-app purchase system Apple provides.

Comment: the idea i had was writing an app which loads all free apps of the best-of list in the appstore and then deleting all of them again. because many developers are pushing their apps for a few days and then they want to have some money for it. but if you have already loaded the app even though it was for free, you do not have to pay for it later if you are interested....

Answer (score 3):

This would be impossible as the iOS sandboxes apps from changing any files not within it's app folder or modifying any other apps.

Answer (score 0):

IF you only would like to load another App inside your App, I think you could try URL Schemes